# how to get EXTRA_DATA from intent that return Search Suggestions results

Tags: android, android-intent, search-suggestion, android-searchmanager

I can get the data for this `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,` by using:

```
intent.getSataString();
```

My question is, how can I get data for this:

```
SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA
```

The context of this question is this:

```
private final static String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        BaseColumns._ID,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA,
        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Android docs, I found this:

> public static final String EXTRA_DATA_KEY
>
> Intent extra data key: This key will be used for the extra populated
>   by the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_EXTRA_DATA column.
>
> Constant Value: "intent_extra_data_key"

So, I tried this:

`String myVal = intent.getExtras().getString(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY)`

This worked perfectly.

Comment: You can mark your question as an answer if it really works

Comment: Yes, this was the answer.  Thanks.  I forgot to mark it.